# Sign apk application before running on device from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

Do you have any suggestions how can I automatically sign my android apk after launching run action from eclipse menu? I want to deploy signed application with my production key because it's demanded by some used APIs.

Comment: what is the problem with export?? just export from menu with your key

Comment: I don't have any problem with export, but I want to sign my apk before run/debug. It'll be simpler way to deploy application during development than export signed apk, move to for example Dropbox and manually install on my device.

Comment: off topic: which api demands production key??

Comment: Google Maps Android API v2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do your builds with Ant, you can get what you want.

> The debug signing process happens automatically when you run or debug
>   your application using Eclipse with the ADT plugin. Debug signing also
>   happens automatically when you use the Ant build script with the debug
>   option. You can automate the release signing process by using the
>   Eclipse Export Wizard or by modifying the Ant build script and
>   building with the release option.

Official [doc](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)